# Excel: Increasing/Decreasing number of columns in table based on number of coloured rows from different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am in the process of creating a costing summary workbook. My main summary sheet lists a job category and then 4 rows of cost breakdown before the next category is listed. On another sheet, I have a template that the user will make a copy of for each month, which breaks down weekly work hours and then allocates hours from each employee/plant to against a job category. Please see attached pictures.

[Summary Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxQzW.png) - 
 [Template Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px2K5.png)

My goal is to have the number of columns on the template increase/decrease as categories are added to or removed from the summary sheet. I already have a cell that contains a count of coloured rows (category titles), and  i figure i should be able to use this to determine the amount of rows that need to be added to or removed from a table. I can't think of any ways for this to be done without macros or VBA code of some kind, which I am open to but I would like to minimise the use of. 
Can anyone provide me with some code or a push in the right direction for this kind of function? Category names will be stored in column A, or my count is stored in B84. Columns for each category start from column S in the template sheet.

Comment: VBA code is an excelent way to solve what you are thinking. That was your question?

Comment: Thanks David, that confirms my train of thought but I am after some code to help me with this. I have edited my question to clear things up.

Comment: That looks like "work", so you could consider hiring someone to do this.  If you know some VBA but are having problems implementing a solution, then posting some code along with as specific problem or error message will likely get you useful responses.

Comment: @C. Kyle are you offering a job? This is not a "code for me" or "free developers to make my job" site. Please don't insult us.

Comment: Very sorry @DavidG., I didn't mean to insult anyone. I suppose you could say this is for 'work', I'm a student and my assessment is looking at methods of job costing and tracking. The workbook is completely functional, this just an 'extra feature' i was looking into. I have little experience with VBA so I'm not sure how to apply anything that I know to this situation. The most I can think of some kind of for loop that will loop through the range of categories, and if the cell is colored, add a column to the table. I don't feel like I know where to start with adding columns to a named table.

Comment: Genuinely just trying to ask for some help here. Even if it is just small functions I could consider using or where I would put the code (Sheet_Activate etc.) or similar pieces of code that I could work out how to adapt. Not trying to use anyones code for personal credit or anything, there's a lot more i'd like to do based on this function so I thought this might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kyle, you can visit the following sites with a lot of vba beginners information.

> http://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html
>   http://www.homeandlearn.org/
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/

Try implementing your idea using pseudo-code.

> http://www.vikingcodeschool.com/software-engineering-basics/what-is-pseudo-coding
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G0EYfrrDT8
>
> https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming/good-practices/p/planning-with-pseudo-code

Once you be able to write your code and you are having some code error or problem you cannot find a solution in the web, come again and ask specific questions, there are a lot of experienced programmers that will be happy to help you to solve your coding problems.